# PHP - Subdomain for each user

Tags: php, apache, redirect, apache2, virtualhost

I have purchased a domain name which I have assigned an **a name** record to my Ubuntu web server. On the server each user has their own profile located at /var/www/user, each user has a sub directory. I need a sub domain for each user in the /user directory.

I started by giving the domain a wildcard '*' a name record which points to the server (as well as @ (obviously)). Then with a Virtual Host I use the wildcard to check for any requests to a sub domain and set their document root to a redirect directory /var/www/redirect. So essentially I'm filtering out sub domain requests and then sending them to the redirect directory to explode the sub domain they requested and forward appropriately.

---

My problem lies with trying to get the original sub domain they requested so I can explode the string and find the user they need and redirect. Does anyone know how I can do this? Should I pass it as a GET variable from Virtual Host or is there a better way?

---

If this sounds like a bad design I'd highly appreciate it if you could suggest a better one!

Comment: Quick question: Have you assumed the case where you might have reserved sub domains for certain things? I'm just thinking of future scenarios. I know deviantart.com does this. my.deviantat.com refers to the current user, yet <yourusername>.deviant.com can go to any arbitrary user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original sub domain they requested is in `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`.